# Where do I give feedback for a Stack Overflow Blog post?

Tags: discussion, blog

I read [this good article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/30/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/?utm_campaign=the-overflow-newsletter) from previous years, and found out that the table formatting is butchered — and perhaps the tags format too?

[image: unrendered table]

I tried to find a way to give feedback to this post, but only found the comment section, which I think wouldn't be read as '*feedback for issues in this post*'. There might be other articles affected too — suspected it happened after the update to Markdown used on SE sites.

How and where can I give feedback for a specific Stack Overflow Blog post?

Answer (score 16):

You have two (three, really) options

- Post on MSE or MSO (your choice, AFAIK) with appropriate tags ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [blog](/questions/tagged/blog), and something pertaining to the issue, like [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown)). Ensure you link to the blog post and clearly describe the issue. Although not required, I sometimes will use a max of four tags (vs. five) to accommodate a status-* tag.
- Leave a comment on the blog - as pointed out by a SE staff member somewhere, if you post a comment on a blog post, the comment will be reviewed by SE staff, so that can work too.

I personally usually use MSE, but all of these are valid options. Arguably commenting on the post is better as Meta posts can get missed (although it's still possible, via options like [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)).